# In-App Purchases with gdx-pay iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, libgdx, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to setup gdx-pay for both Android and iOS to allow me to offer In-App Purchases with my game. I have finished setting up the Android part of the code, but I am having problems with iOS.

I got the In-App Purchase to request and the dialog saying "Confirm Your In-App Purchase" popped up. However, I closed the app without clicking "Cancel" or "Buy" and now I'm having a problem. Whenever I run the game, I get this error:

```
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Products successfully received!
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Purchase observer successfully installed!
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] There are 1 unfinished transactions. Try to finish...
[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Transaction failed: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 
"Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Transaction failed: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
at com.tea.game.ShapeGame$1.handlePurchaseError(ShapeGame.java:78)
at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleTransactionObserver.updatedTransactions(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java:411)
at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleProductsDelegate.didReceiveResponse(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java:299)
at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleProductsDelegate.$cb$productsRequest$didReceiveResponse$(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java)
at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:395)
at com.tea.game.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Transaction failed: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
... 6 more
```

This error states the problem as "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" but I believe that was just because I was running this on the emulator. When I run it on my iPhone, the app crashes at the same point.

I believe it is crashing because it is trying to finish transactions but is unable to ("There are 1 unfinished transactions. Try to finish...")

If anyone could provide a solution/way to prevent this from happening again, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had this problem too. After about half an hour, I had to restart the simulator and then the issue was gone automatically. The transaction was popped up the next time I run the app. I cancelled it and then I can try purchasing it again.